# How to change the name of a Compose preview that uses a PreviewParameter

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to use a `PreviewParameter` to preview Composables with different variants instead of creating a separate function for each state.

Before:

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun VariantAPreview() {
...
}

@Preview
@Composable
private fun VariantBPreview() {
...
}

@Preview
@Composable
private fun VariantCPreview() {
...
}
```

After:

```
@Preview
@Composable
private PreviewAll(@PreviewParameter(Provider::class) data: Data) {
...
}
```

The issue is that the previews are rendered with the function name in the Android Studio design view.

In the example with the separate functions the previews would be named `VariantAPreview`, `VarianteBPreview`, `VariantCPreview`.
When using the PreviewParameter the previews will instead be named as `PreviewAll (data 0)`, `PreviewAll (data 1)`, `PreviewAll (data 2)` which makes it difficult to identify them.

Is there a way to provide a distinguishable preview name when using `PreviewParameter`?

Answer (score 0):

Great Question! I actually can't find a way to do so...
You can give a specific name to your preview by doing so:

```
@Preview(name = "blabla")
```

But I think you already knew that.
Another thing you may already know is that such name can only be a compile-time constant so the best that I could suggest (even tho I've never seen this done and don't know how much I'm forcing things) is that the name of the preview, if you are managing only a few versions of it, could be some sort of legend.

```
const val previewLegend = "0 is A, 1 is B, 2 is C"
@Preview(name = previewLegend)
...
```

It gets kinda long and this "name" gets repeated for each preview but this way you can associate the index to the kind of input your are providing.

That's not great but it could help to have all the info in one place!